# Generalization of anti-derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

I am familiar with the integration of a function $f:D\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ with respect of some variable $x_i \,\,1\leq i \leq n  $.

*For example:* $$\int x\sin (y)\, \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}x^2 \sin(y) + c(x,y)$$

*with* $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}c \equiv 0$$

And this concept is the motivation for my question, so

> could we define a *map* that as argument would have a $(n \times m)$ matrix with entities real valued functions $f_{ij}:D\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}, \, 1 \leq i \leq n, \,  1 \leq j \leq m $ and its value it would be a function $F$ such that $\mathrm{D}F=[ f_{ij}]$ ?

Comment: You could possibly just follow your nose and define a map $I(M)=M_{I}$ such that $I(M_{ij})=\int{M_{ij}\cdot dx}$ where each $M_{ij}$ is one of your specified functions. $M_I$ being your matrix with each entry integrated.

Comment: Strictly speaking I don't think you could call $M_I$, what you call $F$, a 'function'. If I am indeed interpreting your question correctly. It is a matrix whose entries are functions.